# Sum example not working with v3

Tags: lwjgl

Looking at the [Sum example](http://wiki.lwjgl.org/wiki/Sum_Example), I was trying to run it on my local (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS). But it seems that the latest release version `build #3.0.0b build 64
20 Nov 15 18:55`, does not work for that example. Most of the imported classes (in the sum example) from the package org.lwjgl.opencl, do not exist in the v3 jar. AFAIK, there is only 1 jar file in the latest release bundle.

Is there another OpenCL example for v3 which works?

Comment: To folks who are downvoting, can you explain why ? Did you try running the example and did it work for you?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Most of the imported classes (in the sum example) from the package org.lwjgl.opencl, do not exist in the v3 jar of lwjgl. So it does not compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**LWJGL V3.0** has gone through a lot of refactoring. And most of the classes and methods were moved or renamed part of the new build. [**V3.0 Release notes**](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3/blob/master/doc/notes/latest.md) confirms the same.

And as far as I can see, the page that you are referring to was edited almost 3 years back. They might have posted it for practicing 2.X versions at that time.
[image: Metadata from the wiki example]

---

You will have to modify your sample code to incorporate the V3.0 API in order to fix this.

Or you can refer to the new Guide page with a brand new example for LWJGL 3 which can be found **[here](https://www.lwjgl.org/guide#build)**.